# regarding update site

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some questions regarding the eclipse update feature functionality. In generally,what eclipse update is doing is,if it is installing new software it is copies the jar from the specific URL and paste it into the eclipse plugin folder. So If I create my own update functionality to copy from the specific URL and paste into the eclipse plugin folder, will that be enough to finish the job of update site? My requirement is I need to create different look and feel for the update functionality. I don't want to use the UI of eclipse update functionality. What's the correct way to implement update functionality? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we are talking Eclipse 3.5 or later, then you will be using p2, so have a look at [Customizing the p2 UI](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_ui.htm).

It is not generally enough to "just" copy stuff to `plugins/`, as that will not get OSGi to install the new bundle. Use p2 to install your stuff, as it will do the right thing.

As for a completely different UI experience, have a look at the Eclipse Market UI...

Comment: ok. I have one button Install on the dialog. when I click Insall it should fetch the show the available softwares. Generally those softwares will be a plugin. for that osgi installation is mandatory?I did a small example. I created one sample plugin which will contribute one action to the toolbar. And I exported as jar file. When I clicked Install it copies to the plugins folder. After restarting my application it worked fine. Here only my doubt came.

Comment: Look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application That is a complete example on how to do p2 self update...